# Drupal SVG site logo is displaying incorrectly

Tags: svg, drupal

Saving over the top of the existing logo.svg within a custom Drupal theme I am building. The logo does not show on the page (Firefox) and shows extremely large on Safari.

When "inspecting element" I can see that if I add `width=""` (and apply any number) - then the logo will appear in Firefox, and resize in Safari.
But I do not know how to apply a `width` to the `site_logo` within the Drupal theme files. Where would I do this, or alternatively how else would I fix this issue.

The site is in Drupal 8. I've tried moving the branding block into different sections (Nav, sidebar, Content, etc.) but it doesn't rectify the incorrect width issues.

Answer (score 2):

Consider that SVG images not always have `height` and `width` dimensions in their markup, and that adding an SVG file with no dimensions set could affect the styling of your theme.

So open your SVG file in a text editor and ensure to set `width`, `height` and/or `viewBox` according your needs. Or try editing it with some vector image editing tool like Adobe Illustrator or Sketch or Inkscape.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  width="100" height="50"
  viewBox="0 0 200 100">

  <rect x="20" y="20" width="160" height="60"
    fill="limegreen" stroke="black" stroke-width="2px" />
</svg>
```

Comment: In illustrator, you must uncheck the "responsive" box in SVG export settings. Works for FF 60 after.